# Selenium-based screenshot in Jupyter Notebook failing to capture full dataframe

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, jupyter-notebook, selenium-chromedriver, screenshot

I want to use capture a screenshot in Jupyter Notebook which includes all the content from a dataframe (up to 300 records) and for that to be saved as an image file.

The code below works well to capture a screenshot for up to ~49 records, but beyond that it fails to capture any remaining records - and instead includes whitespace (...the amount of which seems to be proportional to the amount of remaining records which are not displayed)

No error messages noted.

One or two of the import statements below may be superflous.

```
import time
import pandas as pd
import os
from PIL import Image
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys 
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

# DataFrame styling code
styled_df = df_SoT_odds_predictions_matching_display_filtered_regular.sort_values(['1+ value'], ascending=False).reset_index(drop=True).style\
    .background_gradient(subset=['xMins', '1+ value', '2+ value', '3+ value'], cmap='RdYlGn')\
    .format(column_precisions)

def dataframe_screenshot(dataframe_name):

    # Save the DataFrame as an HTML file
    dataframe_name.to_html('styled_dataframe.html')

    # Use Selenium to open the HTML file
    driver_path = r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\chromedriver.exe'

    # Use headless mode and set the window size to a larger value
    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--window-size=1920,1080')  # Adjust the window size as needed

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=driver_path, options=chrome_options)

    # Load the HTML file
    # Get the current working directory
    current_directory = os.getcwd()
    # Construct the full path to the HTML file
    html_file_path = os.path.join(current_directory, 'styled_dataframe.html')
    # Load the HTML file
    driver.get(f'file://{html_file_path}')

    # Wait for the page to render
    driver.implicitly_wait(5)

    # Find the DataFrame element by tag name (or any other suitable identifier)
    data_frame_element = driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'table')

    # Get the dimensions of the DataFrame element
    width, height = data_frame_element.size['width'], data_frame_element.size['height']

    # Capture the screenshot of the DataFrame element
    screenshot_path = 'styled_dataframe.png'
    data_frame_element.screenshot(screenshot_path)

    # Close the browser
    driver.quit()

dataframe_screenshot(styled_df)
```